# How to get a wordcloud in a polygon

Tags: r, polygon, data-visualization, word-cloud

I searched hours and hours for the solution of this problem - with much input, but not yet the right solution. I hope somebody can help me out.

**My aim:**
My wordcloud fits in a defined polygon (with x and y coordinates).

**What I have are two main approaches:**

1. Approach: try with R package `wordcloud`

I have:

a) A finished `wordcloud`

```
wordcloud(my_wordcloud, scale=c(4,0.5), max.words=500, min.freq="2", random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.05, use.r.layout=FALSE,colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"))
```

b) A defined polygon

```
plot(my_coordinates, type="l",  axes = F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
```

Now I got both together in a plot with `par(new=TRUE)`. The result is so far:

[image]

As you can see, the words are not matching in my polygon. My problem is that I have no indication for the surrounding area of the `wordcloud`; I don't know where to pass the coordinates of my polygon.

The code for my first approach:

```
#librarys
library("SnowballC", lib.loc="~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1")
library("tm", lib.loc="~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1")
library("wordcloud", lib.loc="~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1")

#Corpus (txt-file)
corp <- Corpus (DirSource("in/test"))
corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)
corp <- tm_map(corp, tolower)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords("german"))
corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
#make a txt-file
corp_clean <- tm_map(corp, PlainTextDocument)

#the coords as csv (columns: x, y)
ch <- read.csv(file="coord/cord_ch.csv", sep = ";")

# Wordcloud
wordcloud(corp_clean, scale=c(4,0.5), max.words=100, min.freq="3", random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.05, use.r.layout=FALSE,colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"))
# new Plot
par(new=TRUE)

#plot the coords
plot(ch, type="l", axes = F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, ylim = rev(range(ch$y)))
```

**Now my second approach:**

2 Approach: text

I came to the following code with the [help of this](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxyZGF0YW1pbmluZ3xneDoyNWRiNmE2NGVhN2QxNGE3):

```
#after some steps from my first approach (we begin with #make a txt-file from above code)
corp_clean <- tm_map(corp, PlainTextDocument)
# some definings
myTdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp_clean)
termFrequency <- rowSums(as.matrix(myTdm))
termFrequency <- subset(termFrequency, termFrequency>=3)
df <- data.frame(term=names(termFrequency), freq=termFrequency)
m <- as.matrix(myTdm)
wordFreq <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE)
#plot the coordinates
plot(ch, type="l", axes = F, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, ylim = rev(range(ch$y)))
par(new=TRUE)
#plot the text (wordcloud) by telling the coordinates
text(x = ch$x, y = ch$y,labels = names(wordFreq))
```

With that code, the resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

Here we have the words in position of the coordinates. Is it possible to declare the coordinates as kind of surrounding-areas for the text?

I hope one of my approaches can be fixed from one of you R-professionals.

Thanks in advance for your help! If you need something more, please let me know!

Comment: I don't think this can be done easily. You may wanna use https://tagul.com/ or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to use R for this...